# Searching for a word ... Further investigation of results from an analyzed study?

Tags: single-word-requests

im searching for the right word in my thesis (my native language is not english). I have conducted a study (interviews) and have already analyzed the results. Now in the next chapter i want to "work" with the results, i want to compare them to other practices and use the results to rate them according to a model. How could i call this, what i'm doing there? The problem is i have already used the word "analysis" in the context of analyzing the data of the interivew.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. As this is an English Language site could you please capitalise the first person singular pronoun 'I' wherever it appears? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider **Comparative assessment**.

> Example: the main objective of this study is to present a
>   comparative assessment between these different modeling techniques, which are
>   usually addressed individually in the literature.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to go deep into similar studies published so far, compare your results with them, and reach a new conclusion, a **"meta-analysis"** may fit.

> - [**meta-analysis**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meta-analysis) -  a quantitative statistical analysis of several separate but similar experiments or studies in order to test the pooled data for statistical significance

but if you only want to mention results of similar papers, **"literature review"** fits better.

> - [**literature review**](http://libguides.library.cqu.edu.au/litreview) - A literature review is an evaluative report of information found in the literature related to your selected area of study.  The review should describe, summarise, evaluate and clarify this literature.

a "literature review" would be better placed at the beginning of a paper, right after the summary and introduction.  But you can also present it at the end, just before the conclusions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your detailed answer and the examples.